# type "string" to “dict” in python

Tags: python

I am a new in python.I am reading a Source code and get some doubt.

```
 if config_path:
        logging.info('loading config from %s' % config_path)
        with open(config_path, 'rb') as f:
            try:
                **config = parse_json_in_str(f.read().decode('utf8'))**
            except ValueError as e:
                logging.error('found an error in config.json: %s',
                              e.message)
                sys.exit(1)
    else:
        config = {}
```

The variable "config" is a string here(parse_json_in_str).Here is the parse_json_in_str:

```
def parse_json_in_str(data):
# parse json and convert everything from unicode to str
return json.loads(data, object_hook=_decode_dict)
```

And then:

```
 v_count = 0
    for key, value in optlist:
        if key == '-p':
            config['server_port'] = int(value)
        elif key == '-k':
            config['password'] = to_bytes(value)
        elif key == '-l':
            config['local_port'] = int(value)
        elif key == '-s':
            config['server'] = to_str(value)
        elif key == '-m':
            config['method'] = to_str(value)
        elif key == '-b':
            config['local_address'] = to_str(value)
        elif key == '-v':
            v_count += 1
            # '-vv' turns on more verbose mode
            config['verbose'] = v_count
        elif key == '-t':
            config['timeout'] = int(value)

        .....
        elif key == '-q':
            v_count -= 1
            config['verbose'] = v_count
except getopt.GetoptError as e:
    print(e, file=sys.stderr)
    print_help(is_local)
    sys.exit(2)
```

why the "config" turn into a dict?

Comment: Without `parse_json_in_str` we can’t understand the code; but I guess it does what it says: parse some JSON in a string and return the parsed value; which in that case seems to be a dict.

Comment: parse_json_in_str prolly takes in a string and returns a dict? dont know without seeing it.

Comment: The json decoder shipped with python should be useful enough.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, json.loads is returning a dictionary ...
[the json docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) say,

> Deserialize s (a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

And the [conversion table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json-to-py-table) says that a json object is converted to a `dict`.